# Loop array from 1 to 5, if reaching 5, start over (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

as my question says, how do I loop through an array which contains 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and when reaching 5, it begins from 1 again.

I want to add a class with called g1, g2, g3 to each element, like this:

```
<div class="myClass g1"></div>
<div class="myClass g2"></div>
```

and so on and fourth... When reaching g5, it begins over with g1...

The problem is that this is iterating and adding g1 g2 g3 g4 and g5 in the same element, I want to split them up into each element.

My code so far:

```
var addGradient = (function() {
    var $serviceModule = $(".service > .service-module > .service-module-bottom");
    var $array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    $serviceModule.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        for (var $i = 1; $i < $array.length; $i++) {
            $this.addClass("g" + $array[$i]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-based, so starting with `$i = 1` will always skip the first array element.  If the `g` suffix is just consecutive numbers there is no need for an array, as Rajaprabhu mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a simple modulo math here. There is no need of array or any loops,

```
var addGradient = (function() {
    var $serviceModule = $(".service > .service-module > .service-module-bottom");
    $serviceModule.each(function(index) {
        $this.addClass("g" + ((index % 5)+1));
    });
});
```

Comment: I was about to cry in another comment why the answers were so complex with for loops and if/else branches. Then your answer saved me the panic attack! Thank you for answering with modulo math!

Comment: @Sukima Glad to help :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, this answer helped me, but it's adding g01, g02, g03... I want g1, g2... Why? :(

Comment: Curious: What if the `$array` of suffixes were strings, not numbers, or were non-consecutive numbers?

Comment: @Flirt That was a typo, just corrected it in my answer. Can you check now?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, YES! Thank you! Worked out great, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo operator:

```
var addGradient = (function() {
    var $serviceModule = $(".service > .service-module > .service-module-bottom");
    $serviceModule.each(function(index) {
        $this.addClass("g" + (index % 5)+1);
    });
});
```

Modulo give you back an integer which is the rest of the division    :

- 5%2 = 1
- 5%3 = 2

It can be used to loop thorough an array too .